# where is the absolute path of header file

Tags: ios, iphone

There is one other person's project, in appDelegate.h

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
#import "SomeController.h"


@interface AppDelegate : UIResponder  
{

}
```

the Somecontroller.h and SomeController.m are at

physical directory 'SomeController' under project sub-directory 'classes'

likes below

```
ProjectName->classes->SomeController->SomeController.h&SomeController.m
```

the structure in XCode is same

```
project->classes->SomeController(group)->SomeController.h&SomeController.m
```

the project can be compiled and run without error, but in 'build setting'-'Frame Search Path' & 'Header Search Path'

only

```
$(inherited) ------------------------non-recursive
$(PROJECT_DIR)/ProjectName-----------non-recursive
$(PROJECT_DIR)/ProjectName/Classes---non-recursive
$(SRCROOT)/ProjectName/Classes-------non-recursive
```

it looks like no one link to the directory

```
ProjectName/classes/SomeController
```

I can not find any place has linked to the path above and confused by the project header file absolute path.

Your comment welcome

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Select target in xcode and then build phases->Compile Sources there is path to the physical folder.

Comment: you are right, but if add the files above  to a new project , everything is same, but it reports error 'SomeController not found'

Comment: how you are adding files ?